# C++ Setters difference of this and :: and =

Tags: c++, setter

I'm a Java developer with some experience. I'm moving to C++ development, and have a question related to setters in C++.

I see some examples where some people use `::` or `this->` or `=` (last 2 are similar to Java) to assign the value, for example

client.h

```
class Client {

    std::string name;

public:

    Client();

    Client(const std::string &name);

public:

    const std::string &getName() const;

    void setName(const std::string &name);

};
```

SETTER VARIATIONS

```
// CLION AUTO GENERATE THIS FIRST CLIENT::NAME

void Client::setName(const std::string &name) {
    Client::name = name;
}


void Client::setName(const std::string &name) {
    this->name = name;
}

void Client::setName(const std::string &newName) {
    name = newName;
}
```

What is the difference between the 3 cases? What are the best or correct form in C++?

Comment: Any C++ code that uses setters such as those is probably bad C++ code.

Comment: `::` is the namespace resolution operator, `this` is the pointer to the address of the object to which the member function is called and the last one assigns the variable `name` to itself. `Cliente::name` resolves to the object named `name` inside the `Cliente` class, `this->name` resolved to the object that is the member of `this` and has the name `name`, and `name` resolves to the parameter you passed to the function. What is the best - all 3 forms are different.

Comment: @NeilButterworth just wondering, what's wrong with the third one except for identical naming of parameter and member variable?

Comment: @Onur They are all wrong because the basic concept of a "setter" is wrong.

Comment: @OnurA. - Funny you should mention the third one. It doesn't modify the member. If the OP saw it in a real codebase, it's one to stay away from.

Comment: Hey Samuaz, you need to dive into the basics of c++ language in order to better grasp the usage of each operator ;-) :: is used in the first to refer to a static member of the class >> it is better in this case for the setter to be a static method too but not mandatory. this-> is used to access a member variable. Member variables or static member variables can also be accessed through their names inside class definition. So clearly you need to use a different name for each, otherwise the compiler wouldn't be very happy ;-)

Comment: @OnurA. (Sorry to be the third person to @ you in a row)  I think the issue is that a setter member function which *just* sets a private member variable borders on exposing that member variable as if it were declared public.  At that rate you might as well just make it actually public and save some boilerplate.

Comment: Now to answer your question, a correct setter would be option 2 and 3, but for 3 make sure the setter's argument has a different name

Comment: Option 3 is definitely wrong - it won't even compile.

Comment: @hegel5000 agree. I actually asked it if I'm missing sth rather than, no-modification or redundant getter/setter classes for plain variable.

Comment: @Hichem - Scope resolution is not just to refer to static members. And please answer in the answer section if intend to answer at all. Thanks.

Comment: @StoryTeller lol, definitely!

Comment: First one is also similar to Java. Java uses the `.` rather than `::` to access static members.

Comment: @StoryTeller: I know that scope resolution is not about only static members, but the context here is setters, so no need to go further and make things more complex than they are...

Comment: @Hichem - Simplification is good. But that is not what you did. Your choice of words clearly stated that member is to be static in option 1. Which is clearly not true. Misleading is worse than over-complicating. So in the future, answer in the answer section, where the site's quality control mechanism can be used to properly rate your answers.

Comment: Some C++ programmers would say having a parameter name the same as the member variable name is a bad idea.  (I'm in that camp.  But the language allows shadowing the name of the member variable, and some C++ developers do it regularly.  So it exists in the wild, aplenty.)

Comment: Please post real code samples.  Asking answerers to read your mind and work out if your code errors betray a real misunderstanding or a typo is a waste of everyone's time.  Build your code, and copy/paste from building code.

Comment: sorry guys a fix the gramma and also include the client.h file to make it more clear

Comment: @StoryTeller we are talking about good coding habits and conventions (options 2 and 3 are commonly used). scope resolution operator is used with static or when you deal with inheritance conflicts ; we don't see it in member function definition or setters. For a newcomer to C++ programming, using form 2 and 3 is what he has to know

Comment: @HichemBOUSSETTA - Coding *style* is about culture, and highly subjective. There is no "we" here. The only thing a novice should learn is to not get in the habit of substituting one's own style preference for universally "good style".

Comment: @StoryTeller I fully understand and respect your point of view, and stick to mine :-)

Answer (score -1):

- I'll assume you meant Client where you wrote Cliente

First case:

```
void Client::setName(const std::string &name) {
    Cliente::name = name;
}
```

In this case, name is a static string variable under the Client class. the :: operator means that the following function / variable is a member of this class, and that it is static. (Therefore when you call setName, it will set the name for all the variables of this type!)

Second case:

```
void Cliente::setName(const std::string &name) {
    this->name = name;
}
```

In this case, name is a variable that isn't static inside the class, and is relative to each specific object. For example, if You would have Client c1 and Client c2 and change the name of c1, c2's name will remain unchanged. the -> operator is similar to the . operator in java - it means it's relative to this object, except in c++ you use the dot when you're messing with object variables, and the arrow with pointers to object variables. "this" is a pointer to the current object you're dealing with, and that's why you use the arrow operator. It's just an easier way of writing (*this).name

```
void Cliente::setName(const std::string &name) {
    name = name;
}
```

I assume the left name is a variable inside Client. Well, when you're writing inside the class you don't have to write this-> because it takes the current object's variables as default, So there's no difference between the second and third case, but when you're outside of the class you have to specify which object are you referring to.

Comment: `Client::name` can refer to a non-static member of the current object. And there’s nothing that says its type is string. `this->name` can be used to refer to a static member as well as a non-static member. And in `name = name` both refer to the argument. It hides any data member with the same name. There’s a different rule for `name(name)` in an initializer list, but that doesn’t apply here.